# Difficulty with Sending email using cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp

sure it is giving me a headache but i do understand that every beginner goes the same experience. I've tried every tutorial i found about sending email using cakephp. Well, nothing worked. Can I have a link to a better tutorial about cakephp email. The manual isn't complete as well  :(  im kinda frustrated  :(

I have tried this code:

```
<?php
    class EmailsController extends AppController{

 var $components = array('Email');

function sendNewUserMail() {
    //$User = $this->User->read(null,$id);
    $this->Email->to = 'csorila17@gmail.com';
    $this->Email->bcc = array('secret@example.com');  
    $this->Email->subject = 'Welcome to our really cool thing';
    $this->Email->replyTo = 'support@example.com';
    $this->Email->from = 'Cool Web App <charm_sorila@yahoo.com>';
    $this->Email->template = 'simple_message'; // note no '.ctp'
    //Send as 'html', 'text' or 'both' (default is 'text')
    $this->Email->sendAs = 'both'; // because we like to send pretty mail
    //Set view variables as normal
    $this->set('User', $User);
    //Do not pass any args to send()
    $this->Email->send();
    echo "hi";
 }
    }
?>
```

it is saved in this folder:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\NewFolder\app\webroot\email\app\controllers
```

so what i type in my url everytime i try to run this in my browser is this: `http://localhost/email/sendNewUserMail

what my browser gives me is a blank page and nothing is being sent to csorila17@gmail.com. What could possibly be the problem? if it is possible guys, can i take a look at a complete code for sending email using cakephp? this problem drives me crazy. Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check your logs for any error messages?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? 1.x and 2.x send emails differently.  Your code looks like you are trying to use a 1.x solution, but I would like to know before trying to answer your question.

Comment: im using the 1.3.0 version. well, the log doesn't seem to work as well. Is this how you output log: $this->logs(); .. ive done it as what i found in my research but same thing. Even the lines above: echo "hi";, it is not displaying...

Comment: I think your url is wrong `http://localhost/emails/sendNewUserMail` (notice the 's') first of all. Second, turn on debug to see an errors instead of a blank page.

Comment: ive already set the debug mode to 2, still it gives me a blank page. It doesnt even echo out anything. :(

Comment: is there any pre-configuration in any other files that i need to do before i could actually code for sending emails?

Comment: im also following this tutorial: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/GreyCells/2007/01/02/brief-overview-of-the-new-emailcomponent ... but i still get a blank page

Comment: look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669012/cakephp-2-cakeemail-could-not-send-email-error/19875079#19875079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this application locally, I believe you need to setup a mail server to work, otherwise you can use smtp mail option with any of the provider. For that you have to configure your mail settings.

In your `app\config` you can create a file `email.php`

```
<?php 
    class EmailConfig {

        public $default = array(
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'username' => 'your email address', //example@gmail.com
            'password' => 'password',
            'transport' => 'Smtp',
            'from' => array('From Email Address' => 'Name to be displayed in the Email'),
            'log' => true
        );

    }
```

After this in your controller you can setup use the following code to send email.

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->to('example@gmail.com');
$email->subject('Email testing Subject');       
$email->send('Email testing content');
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, important to know version number. Make sure debug is set to "2" in your config file so you can see some output.